# Will mvapich be substantially better than openmpi? And How?

Tags: mpi

I am a Computational Fluid Dynamist (CFD), but I dont know mpi very well.

Since heavy CFD jobs requires Infiniband support, and people say that mvapich is usually much better than other mpi implementations. I want to know is this true? Any one has any real experience and references that I can look at? And how come that mvapich is better than the openmpi, etc.? Is it written by Infiniband company or what?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Many people consider Open MPI to deliver somewhat worse performance on InfiniBand networks than MVAPICH. Then one day some of these people type `ompi_info --param btl openib` just to find out that there are 70+ parameters than can be tweaked to get the best performance out of a **specific application** (no silver bullets, sorry). Btw, "X vs Y" questions are considered unconstructive on SO. Pleas, only post questions related to programming here.

Comment: note in Open MPI, there are two ways to use native infiniband: the openib btl (quite standard) or the mxm mtl which is based on top of mellanox proprietary library. the latter is worth evaluating since it can leads to increased performances, especially regarding the message rate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the answer is "probably not, and it doesn't matter anyway".

You write your code using the MPI API, and you can always install multiple MPI libraries and test against each, as you might with several LAPACK implementations.   If one's consistently faster for your application, use it.  But the MPI community is very concerned with performance, and the free competitors are all open source and publish their methods in papers, and all publish lots of benchmarks.  The friendly rivalary, combined with the openness, tends to mean that no implementation has significant performance advantages for long.

On our big x86 cluster we've done "real world" and micro benchmarks with MPICH2, OpenMPI, MVAPICH2, and IntelMPI.  Amongst the three open-source versions, there was no clear winner; on some cases one would win by 10-20%, on others it would lose by the same amount.  On those few occassions where we were interested enough to dig into the details to find out why, it was often just a matter of defaults for things like eager limits or crossover between different collective algorithms, and by setting a couple of environment variables we got performance within noise between them.   In other cases, a performance advantage persisted but was either not large enough or not consistent enough for us to investigate further.

(IntelMPI, which costs significant amounts of money, *was* noticibly and mostly-consistently faster, although what we consider the big win there was substantially improved startup times for very large jobs.)

MVAPICH was one of the first MPI implementations to really go after Infiniband performance, after having lots of experience with Myrinet, and they did have a significant advantage there for quite some time, and there are probably benchmarks in which they still win; but ultimately there was no consistent and important performance win and we went with OpenMPI for our main Open Source MPI option.

Comment: Fun fact: Intel MPI, which costs significant amounts of money, doesn't play well with LSF, which costs even more significant amounts of money, when it comes to large jobs :) That's why we recommend Open MPI to all of our heavy MPI users.

Comment: The integration into torque is imperfect, too, meaning we don't automatically get useful integrated data like cpu time, memory usage, etc back.

Answer (score 8):

I would agree with Jonathan regarding the answer and add a few points from a cluster administration perspective.

As a person who at times dips into cluster administration I would add that tuning InfiniBand on a large cluster is not an easy task. You have to make sure that the OFED stack sits well upon your kernel. That the hardware is not faulty and the switches are working as expected without performance issues in a sustained mode and the application maps correctly onto the InfiniBand topology and lots more.

OpenMPI stack is considerably different from MPICH/MVAPICH. I find that OpenMPI component architecture makes it easier to find and debug issues than the architecture of MPICH/MVAPICH which I find more monolithic.

Speaking of vendors recall that **MPICH** comes from the MCS department of Argonne.

**Update:** Since version 3.1 MPICH supports OFED InfiniBand via the ib network module. Since 3.2 MPICH will support also the Mellanox MXM interface.

**MVAPICH** is built on top of MPICH sources by the people from the department of CS&E at Ohio State.

Many hardware vendors build either on top of MPICH or MVAPICH to provide InfiniBand support for their respective HW. One example is **Intel MPI**. Another is **Voltaire MPI**.

**OpenMPI** is developed by several teams supported by InfiniBand switch vendors like Cisco.

**HP MPI** used to be another very good MPI implementation for *generic* clusters that is currently available from Platfrom.

Answer (score 2):

CFL codes don't scale well.

I can't speak directly to MVAPICH2, but I would recommend using whatever MPI is native to your cluster. So if you are using a Cray machine, you would go with Cray's MPI. It works like magic. Using your vendors recommended mpi makes a significant difference.

To directly answer your question, if your message size falls in the short range MVAPICH2 has a sweet spot where it beats OpenMPI. I think your CFL codes may fall in this range. On large clusters I have found that something goes wrong with MVAPICH2 with latency values when operating on over 2k PEs - but people don't run CFL on 2k PEs.

Ultimately, there is sufficient motivation to test this theory. Which code are you running OpenFOAM, Fluent?

Comment: Speak for yourself, I routinely run fluid simulations on tens of thousands of cores.  "CFD" covers a lot of ground.

Comment: @Misha Thanks a lot! I develop and use based on OpenFOAM, especially in unsteady simulation, when it's larger than 512 cores, it becomes very slow, no substantial improvement any more, so I am wondering what might be going wrong.

Comment: @JonathanDursi Thanks, how many grid points you set for each processor? 20k~30k, or what? Are you running steady or unsteady analysis?

Comment: Unsteady, and it's compressible, both of which make it much easier to scale.   Just want to remind people that scaling depends a lot on what science, problem size, and algorithms one needs, even within a given field.

Comment: One guy told me he found compressible solver scales much better than the incompressible solver, and suggested me to run my incompressible flow case with compressible flow solver. Are you also holding the same opinion? Another question is, my observation is, I found multigrid is not that robust as it claims to be in unsteady simulations, perhaps its only good in steady RANS. But I am not sure, what's your finding? Which algorithm are you using for matrix solution. Thanks

Comment: People run CFD on 1.6M MPI processes of Blue Gene/Q regularly. Claims of non-scaling indicate software design failure.